# Choose one dependency as precedent over another for an arbitrary list of packages in the IntelliJ Builder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

**Goal**

I'm trying to make my maven project use the `IntelliJ` builder when I'm editing code because the IDE offers fast rebuild and hot deployment features that could speed up my work. However I'm running into a roadblock due to how my maven project is set up.

**Constraints**

I have to use maven the way it's being used. The solution must be in `IntelliJ`

Note that creating an `IntelliJ` plugin is an option. I realize this may be necessary due to the limitations of `IntelliJ` build configuration.

**The problem**

My project depends on 2 libraries, `SharedLibA` and `SharedLibB`, which contain package com.shared. `SharedLibA` is a new library, and `sharedLibB` is and old legacy one. `SharedLibA` and `SharedLibB` contain packages that are not contained in the other, which are needed by my project. The package they both have, com.shared is needed by the project too. However `SharedLibB` is legacy/old so we always want Tomcat to prioritize the implementation of classes in com.shared from `SharedLibA`, not the implementations of those classes in `SharedLibB`. We accomplish this by having a maven goal that extracts classes under package com.shared from `SharedLibA` to WEB-INF/classes when the WAR is packaged.

When I try to build my project in `IntelliJ`, it picks up the wrong implementation of classes in com.shared.* and spews out compilation errors despite compilation working perfectly via maven. I'm stuck with this inflexible maven `hackjob` but I still want to find a way to make `IntelliJ` understand that I want `SharedLibA's` com.shared.* classes to be used in compilation not `SharedLibB's`. I can't remove `SharedLibB` from consideration because I need the other classes in `SharedLibB` to compile my project.

**Desired Solution**

I'm looking for some kind of logic like "when com.shared.* classes are considered, choose `SharedLibA`" or "when any package conflict happens in classpath resolution, prioritize `ShareLibA`" because I'm pretty sure `SharedLibA` should be prioritized in any package conflict.

**Thanks**

I hope that explains it well enough, thank you in advance to anyone who chimes in here.

Comment: The best solution would be to make changes to the Maven project or its dependencies. Why do you rule that out?

Answer (score 1):

IDE [builds](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_module) the classpath and buildpath based on the dependencies which are [configured for the module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html). It also considers [their order](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#sort-dependencies) -  the 1st dependency that match given class will be used.

For Maven-based projects the dependencies list and their order IDE takes from the Maven pom.xml file of the module. So you can set the order in pom.xml file.

Another mentioned option is to [exclude the library items](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#excluded_lib_items). But the better solution would be to configure Maven build properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to go to your project ".IML" file and there :
you can create or modify a module.

In there you can include or exclude the libs or defining its use priority
you could use this snippet to inspire

```html
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="8">
  <component name="SharedB" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
...
    <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
...
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
...
  </component>
</module>
```

if you are not confortable with this solution you could use the module settings of Intellij

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#excluded_lib_items